# Tikz tools like mathpix ？

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Is there some tool for converting graphics into tikz code, just like mathpix converting a formula to a code?

Comment: Max welcome to TEXSE, mentioning just as graphics is a very vague term (in scripting analogy). First, what do you mean by graphics? `:-)`. Nevertheless, there are a few tools that I am aware of. For example, `matlab2tikz` and `inkscape`. Not to mention, mostly always the best way to do with is by scritpting them yourself  `;)`

Comment: Yes, this tool exists. It is this very site. You only need to post a question with title "How can I draw this?" and add the screen shot of what you want to achieve. Then you will get the code in an answer. ;-)

Comment: Possible help for your question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the editor from https://www.mathcha.io/
In the editor you can insert a diagram, which allows you to draw many shapes and figures.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to start with, and then see if it has a TiKz export option.  In addition to the ones above, there's an answer here
[Need help to export tikz code from geogebra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445331/need-help-to-export-tikz-code-from-geogebra)
about Geogebra -> Tikz