# Geogebra package in LaTeX

Tags: geogebra

Is there a package that supports [all the commands of Geogebra](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Category:Commands) to use with `LaTeX`?

Comment: It's probably easiest to do the actual work in Geogebra, then export to Ti*k*Z and use that in your `.tex` file. See this thread to get you started: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445331/

Answer (score 1):

> Comment converted to community answer (comment by user [ingmar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/26614/ingmar)).

- It's probably easiest to do the actual work in Geogebra, then export
  to TikZ and use that in your .tex file.
- See this thread to get you
  started: [Need help to export tikz code from geogebra](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445331).